# Big Endian distribution for the Raspberry Pi

Tags: arm, software-recommendation

I have an application that I'm writing on a little endian x86 system, but I would like to test it on a big endian processor to ensure compatibility.  I understand that the ARM processor can go big endian or little endian, but by default the Raspberry Pi is little endian.  Is there a big endian distribution/operating system available?  If not, what am I looking at to construct one?  Is it possible with the Raspberry Pi?

Thanks!

Comment: Not all "big endian"s are created equal, ARM as a company supports two different big endian modes (mutually exclusive as far as I know, cores either support one or the other) BE32 and BE8, either 32 bit invariant (the older arms) and 8 bit invariant.  the raspberry pi will support one or the other, as far as getting a working distro, good luck...

Comment: If all you want is to test big-endianness, you could try some distribution on qemu (not necessarily raspberry pi). OpenWRT runs on qemu's big endian ARM emulator.

Answer (score 1):

There's an `Endianness` option in `Target Options`, you may select and change when building a new kernel for your device. I haven't tried it myself, but it just might work.

Unfortunately, I don't know of any precompiled big-endian distributions for ARM. However, there's an article "[Building a Big Endian ARM Cross Compiler Toolchain](http://www.davehylands.com/linux/ARM-bigendian/)", a bit outdated, but still useful.

Comment: I am facing the same thing, but I can't find the Target Options within the menuconfig of the arm itself. If I am building the cross compiler itself I can select it, but it seems to make no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I have built a big endian tool chain, a big endian kernel using buildroot to no avail. Something tells me that the *bootloader* must set the processor in big endian mode before it jumps to the kernel, but the bootloaders are closed. Maybe its not a bad idea to consider uboot...